# Saving final build version in TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I am using **file content replacer** ***Build Feature*** to change the `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` but I do not see any option to save the final version in TeamCity so that I can use it somewhere else down the build step.

Any pointers on how to achieve this is really appreciated.

Comment: Look into artifact dependency. All the downstream projects, which depend on a given build, will get the compiled sources with that version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to define a build parameter that will hold the version. You can set it by concatenating a few other build parameters. For example define a parameter named "version.number" and set it to **1.0.%build.number%**

Then you can use that parameter in both: build feature and in other build steps.